# Problem converting jupyter notebook to slides

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/docs/source/usage.rst) to convert my Jupyter notebook to slides but I am getting the following errors. Can someone suggest a solution?

I am running Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 and nbconvert 6.0.7 on Manjaro. It seems that nbconvert is unable to find the correct template. I am producing a part of the error message because I am not being allowed to post the entire output of the console.

```
~ >>> jupyter nbconvert slides.ipynb --to slides --reveal-prefix reveal.js                                                                           
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook slides.ipynb to slides
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('nbconvert==6.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-nbconvert')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance

.
.
.
.
    code = """<style type="text/css">\n%s</style>""" % (env.loader.get_source(env, name)[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 420, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: static/index.css
```